# Does magento offers a crud CLI

Tags: magento2, code-generation, crud

I was wondering if magento was offering a CRUD CLI like Symfony would do. You get a prompt that ask you your entity fields and once your entered them all then the entity and it's related repository is generated automatically.

Does magento offers some kind of similar functionnality ? Or may be threw a third party module ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhpStorm as an IDE, you should check out the Magento plugin for PhpStorm which adds a lot of cool features related to Magento development to the IDE: https://github.com/magento/magento2-phpstorm-plugin